# java com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util does not exist

Tags: java, import

I can run my java project correctly but can't build the jar file

Each time I try to build the project I get:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util does not exist
```

Caused by this line:

```
import static com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util.ASCIIUtility.getBytes;
```

When removed, `getBytes` fails.

```
InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
byte[] bytesFile = getBytes(iStream);
```

Which is the correct lib or any other way to get the bytes array from file?

Comment: com.sun is getting deprecated due to security vulnerability, I suggest using some other lib...

Answer (score 0):

You should use what's available in the standard library for java.nio.file.Files

```
byte[] bytesFile = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)